# Reverse enginering native DLL with IDA to extract constants

Tags: dll, native, reverse-engineering, ida

I need to find some constant values from a native DLL.
I could find their names, but I cannot understand how to get values.

These are all constants names that i'm looking for:

```
brCustom, br110, br300, ... br9600, ...
```

And here is where I found them in decoded code view:

```
.text:004092E8 off_4092E8      dd offset @$xp$15Cpdrv@Rate ; DATA XREF: .text:00409300o
.text:004092E8                                         ; .text:004097A5o
.text:004092E8                                         ; `__DPdsc__'[Cpdrv::Rate]
.text:004092EC ; Exported entry  31. @$xp$15Cpdrv@Rate
.text:004092EC                 public @$xp$15Cpdrv@Rate
.text:004092EC ; `__DPdsc__'[Cpdrv::Rate]
.text:004092EC @$xp$15Cpdrv@Rate db 3             ; DATA XREF: .text:off_4092E8o
.text:004092EC                                         ; Enumeration
.text:004092ED                 db 9,'Rate'
.text:004092F7                 db 1                    ; uchar - min/max
.text:004092F8                 dd 0, 0Fh
.text:00409300                 dd offset off_4092E8
.text:00409304                 db 8,'brCustom'
.text:0040930D                 db 5,'br110'
.text:00409313                 db 5,'br300'
.text:00409319                 db 5,'br600'
.text:0040931F                 db 6,'br1200'
.text:00409326                 db 6,'br2400'
.text:0040932D                 db 6,'br4800'
.text:00409334                 db 6,'br9600'
.text:0040933B                 db 7,'br14400'
.text:00409343                 db 7,'br19200'
.text:0040934B                 db 7,'br38400'
.text:00409353                 db 7,'br56000'
.text:0040935B                 db 7,'br57600'
.text:00409363                 db 8,'br115200'
.text:0040936C                 db 8,'br128000'
.text:00409375                 db 8,'br256000'
```

For example I know that br9600 has a value of 4, but how can I found it?

Answer (score 0):

there should be a list, that has the offsets of each strings beginning, the index in that table is your enum-id

Comment: Where is the enum-id?